# Are old links updated automatically?

Tags: bug, status-completed

There are still links pointing to the old site(?). Will they be updated automatically?

Comment: A most excellent question.

Answer (score 5):

We have a redirect rule in place that will automatically send these links to the correct location.

Comment: You Stack Overflow dudes absolutely rock.  Thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Appears so

[http://www.google.com/search?q=Should+I+finance+a+new+home+theater+at+0%25+even+though+I+have+the+cash+for+it%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&safe=active](http://www.google.com/search?q=Should+I+finance+a+new+home+theater+at+0%25+even+though+I+have+the+cash+for+it%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&safe=active)

We should ask on the webmaster site if the canoncial rule will keep our SEO.