# Bug: BasicallyMoney.com links do not show up in linked question side bar

Tags: bug, status-completed

Related to [Are old links updated automatically?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/are-old-links-updated-automatically), If a question links to another question on BasicallyMoney.com, those questions do not show up on the linked sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

We can't reproduce this. As you can see on this very post, the post you linked shows up.

Oh, I see -- I replaced all instances of `http://basicallymoney.com` with `http://money.stackexchange.com` for now.

As posts are edited and links are updated naturally over time (this happens on page load a small percent of the time) this should fix itself.

Comment: AlexB is referring to older questions on the actual parent site that link to the previous domain name in the URL, i.e. contain "basicallymoney.com" in the URL.  For instance, refer to http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/951/hearing-much-about-dave-ramsey-which-of-his-works-is-best-in-describing-his-phi ... all of those questions that are linked to in the question body don't appear in the "Linked" section at the right.

Comment: As a for-instance, I just edited the first question in the list at that question to point to "money.stackexchange.com" instead, and now it shows up in the "Linked" section.  So, the "Linked" section doesn't appear to be looking for synonyms of the site domain name.

Comment: @ChrisWRea Thanks for the example.  I should have included that in my original post.

Comment: So this [question ](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/951/hearing-much-about-dave-ramsey-which-of-his-works-is-best-in-describing-his-phi) will have 5 linked questions fixed auto-magically over time (instead of just the 1 it currently has)?   What triggers the fix? an edit or just a page load?

Comment: @alex sure just requires a trivial edit to trigger the linked question rebuild. I did so.. (though, somehow not all the URLs were replaced in the post when I ran the replace)